# Не совпадает размерность финального дата фрейма и размерностью объеденных. В чем может быть проблема

Tags: pandas, numpy

Всем привет,

Задача очень простая, как по мне, но не могу понять почему так происходит.
У меня есть 2 датафрейма: 
data_categ и data_count
Их размености такие:

```
data_categ.shape
(1338, 229)

data_count.shape
(1338, 36)
```

Хочу их соеденить в один (добавить справа):

```
result = pd.concat([data_categ, data_count], axis=1)
```

Размер финальной матрицы:

```
result.shape
(1453, 265)
```

Почему у меня 1453 строки, вместо 1338? При чем, как-то хаотично все объеденило. 
Как объеденить, чтобы размер был 1338 Х 265? 
Спасибо

Comment: Что показывает `print(data_categ.index.is_unique)` и `print(data_count.index.is_unique)`?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, разобрался. Просто смерджил сеты и все заработало)